# call .asp page on button click and jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I have a .asp page that creates and excel based on data from database. Now I need to just open this page and create excel on click of a button using jquery ajax. The code that I tried is as below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#export_excel").on("click", function(){
                alert("Calling");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/ExcelExport.asp",
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

After some time I am getting 500 Internal error. Can anybody guide me how to accomplish this.

ExportExcel.asp

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<!--#include file="ADOVBS.inc"-->
<!--#include file="IASUtil.asp"-->
<!--#include file="includes\cdsconnection.inc"-->
<%
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Export.xls"
    theSQL = Session("RPT")

    Set RS = Connection.Execute(theSQL)
%>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>CDS Return Report Anticipated</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Customer Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Dispute ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Dispute Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    INVOICE NUMBER
                </th>
                <th>
                    CUST PO NUMBER
                </th>
                <th>
                    DISPUTE AMOUNT
                </th>
                <th>
                    TMP ORDER NUMBER
                </th>
                <th>
                    STATUS DESCRIPTION
                </th>
                <th>
                    DISPUTE CLS DATE
                </th>
                <th>
                    ROOT CAUSE DESCRIPTION
                </th>
                <th>
                    NOTES
                </th>
                <th>
                    DMRM
                </th>
                <th>
                    ITEM ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    DATE RECEIVED
                </th>
                <th>
                    ORDER NUMBER
                </th>
                <th>
                    SPECREQ
                </th>
                <th>
                    ITEM NUMBER
                </th>
                <th>
                    DIS COMCODE
                </th>
                <th>
                    DIS QUANTITY
                </th>
                <th>
                    QTYRCVD
                </th>
                <th>
                    DIS_EXT_PRICE
                </th>
            </tr>
            <% DO UNTIL RS.eof  %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("CUSTOMER_NAME") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("DISPUTE_ID") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("DISP_DATE") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("INVOICE_NUM") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("CUST_PONUM") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("DISP_AMOUNT") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("TMP_ORDERNUM") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("STATUS_DESCRIPTION") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("DISP_CLS_DATE") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("ROOT CAUSE DESCRIPTION") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("NOTES") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("DMRM") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("ITEM_ID") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("DATERCVD") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("ORDERNUM") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("SPECREQ") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("ITEM_NUM") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("DIS_COMCODE") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("DIS_QUANTITY") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("QTYRCVD") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= RS("DIS_EXT_PRICE") %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% RS.MoveNext 
                LOOP%>
                <%Response.End()%>
        </table>
    </body>

    </html>
```

RPT is a session variable containing the query. For security reasons I cannot provide full query here. But I have ran the query against our oracle DB. It fetches around 10,000 records. So I added a ROWNUM <= 30 in the where condition. Now I am not getting any error in AJAX call. Status is 200. But .xls file was not generated.

Please let me know the mistake I am doing here.

Comment: What happens if you call the ExcelExport.asp page directly? Do you get a server error there as well?

Comment: Check your URL path. And insert a break point to code behind.

Comment: No if I call the page directly I don't get error. All the pages are in the same folder.

Comment: Hi Bob I am using classic asp not asp.net. That's where the confusion is.

Comment: Is the way I am accessing the page using Ajax correct?

Comment: Is the way I am accessing the page using Ajax correct?

Comment: have you looked under the Network Tab in the Developer Tools for more info (this is for Chrome)? This will hopefully tell you the error message.

Comment: As Bob said. Put a break point in the code.  You can use Visual Studio to debug ASP classic code.  (You have to configure IIS settings to allow debugging and attach Visual Studio to the w3 process.)

Comment: I am creating the pages on my local system and transferring them to a windows 2003 server where a site is already present. I am creating some pages for reporting which has Excel Export Functionality. So I am not able to use any debugging features of VS.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery in my network tab it just stays at pending. When I click on ExportExcel.asp and see timing it says request not processed yet

Comment: I tried with the code onclick="window.open('ExcelExport.asp', '_blank') 
I am getting site is temporarily down error. The excel file being generated is pretty big. Any suggestions.

Comment: Make a simple `.asp` file with just a `response.write` statement and try calling that through ajax and see what happens.

Comment: I even tried to add a 1 minute time out for the ajax call. But after a few seconds the request was cancelled - as shown in the network tab.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ I wrote a .asp with a simple response.write. In the network tab the status is 200 (OK).

Comment: Then you will have to debug the asp page `ExcelExport.asp`. You could [edit] and add the code with your question.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ I have edited my question by adding the ExportExcel.asp code. Sorry I could not provide the sql query being used.

Comment: Comment out the `Response.end` and try with the limited rows version again

Comment: Hi I got the whole html page as response in my console - with data. But .xls is not generated and downloaded to user system. Should I add any code for that to happen. Or if i remove the success callback from ajax will it happen?

Comment: I tried by removing success callback. .xls file is not generated. But I see some KB being transferred in Chrome's Network Tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147266/discussion-between-searchandresq-and-abhilash-d-k).

Comment: You'll need to look in to Response.BinaryWrite for sending the .asp excel output back to your ajax call. Then you'll want to modify the .asp code to store the generated data from your query (currently HTML with a header change to spoof excel) in a byte array you can pas to BinaryWrite. Lastly you'll want to add the correct contentType to your ajax arguments (maybe application/vnd.ms-excel or application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet) so it knows to expect the data. https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_binarywrite.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply I did not know about BinaryWrite. Will definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the ajax call and inserting my button in a form tag with action="ExportExcel.asp". Thanks to @SearchAndResQ for pointing that out. My motto was not to navigate to ExportExcel.asp page. So tried to do with Ajax. @mjw pointed out about Response.BinaryWrite. I have not tried that. I will try and it will be nice one to keep in my arsenal.